# Client-side concatenate a server-side string using evaluate() in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to understand the behaviour of `evaluate`. For a simple example say I have a server-side string that I want to concatenate something to.

```
var serverString = ee.String('asdf')
```

First, try and use evaluate to concatenate something

```
print(serverString.evaluate(function(val){return val + '!'})) // undefined
```

Second, write the function to print directly.

```
serverString.evaluate(function(val){print( val + '!')}) // works as expected
```

Why does the first attempt fail while the second succeeds? Why is printing the returned value of a function undefined?

View in code editor https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fcaseyengstrom%2Freprex%3AevaluateTest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.evaluate()` *does not return anything* (or more precisely, it always returns `undefined`). It cannot, because the *callback* function you have given it has not yet been called.

In general, `x.evaluate(f)` will:

1. Start a request to the Earth Engine servers to compute `x`.
2. Remember that `f`, the function you provided, should be called *when the answer is ready.*
3. Return.

Then, some time later, the request finishes and `f` is called. Thus, the code you write *around or after* `evaluate()` will always finish running *before* the callback function is called.

This code will always print "A", "B", and "C" in that order:

```js
print('A');
ee.String('C').evaluate(function(val){
  print(val);
});
print('B');
```